# I have a lot of Kubernetes processes installed when i haven't installed it (what do i do and how do i delete it)

Tags: kubernetes

[image: Running Netstat in terminal]
[image: Kubectl Version]

I have no clue how it got installed and why it got installed. I do have docker installed but i don't have Kubernetes installed via docker. I was assuming it was due to killer intelligence but i got no idea how to verify or check that.

Comment: Which pods and other stuff is deployed? Can you execute kubectl get all -A and post the output?

Comment: Well I can access kubectl. As you can see in the second image I was able to get the version

Comment: Ok got your issue now. What does a ps -ef reveal? Something related to kubernetes?

Comment: i get: `Get-Process : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ef'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a kubernetes process. This is a result of installing docker and how it configures itself to *enable* you to run kubernetes locally. The string "kubernetes" is coming from your `hosts` file even though you might not have turned on the feature to use k8s.

If you open `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`, you'll see a line that associates "kubernetes" with 127.0.0.1, your `localhost`.
So, while `netstat` may show "kubernetes" as the destination address, it's a little misleading because anything going to 127.0.0.1 will show up as "kubernetes".

`netstat -ab` will show the executable associated with each connection if you want to verify.

Comment: Hmm, I do have docker installed but i never enabled kubernetes via docker. If i was to delete docker would kubernetes uninstall itself?

Comment: @Redfer You don't have kubernetes installed. What you're seeing with `netstat` is a result of the change in your "hosts" file. I've updated my answer for clarification.